# wordpress - need to add custom php (to be called by AJAX), but not in a theme

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have a wordpress application, and in one page, I need to make an AJAX call to some custom PHP file. The custom PHP code will create an image file and save it in a directory. Is it safe to store images in a custom directory at the root?

Where is a good place to place this custom PHP file? Should I place it in a newly created folder at the root? Or will it be deleted if wordpress is updated? Do I need to create a plug-in for this?

Comment: May want to review WP Plugins that can allow you to add PHP to specific pages or posts. What steps have you tried so far?

Comment: @twisty - I still haven't tried anything. So you recommend using an existing plugin... maybe, I will do that.

Comment: Yes, there are some good ones that will allow you to create code snippets that can be added to posts or pages. This makes it easier to update WP without having to recreate and re-add hard coded PHP back into templates and such.

Comment: @twisty, Will this work in my case, however? I don't want to add PHP "output" to the page itself. I want to call it through AJAX.

Comment: Yes, with the plugins I have used, you create the snippet and then add the snippet code to the post/page. Then your selected PHP Code is then executed when you execute the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better if you use a custom directory inside of the uploads folder of the site to store images. Create it and then chmod 775

Place the form in the page template for your page. Add an empty div with a class "upload-response". Just before the closing of the container div, insert a script tag that will echo the admin-ajax.php path to a js variable:

```
<script>
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>';
</script>
```

I used jQuery to handle the rest (the contents of the upload.js file):

```
(function ($) {
$('body').on('click', '.upload-form .btn-upload', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();


    var imagedata = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    var fd = new FormData();
    //var files_data = imagedata;
    fd.append('image', imagedata);

    // our AJAX identifier
    fd.append('action', 'my_upload_files');  

    // Remove this code if you do not want to associate your uploads to the current page.
    //fd.append('post_id', <?php echo $post->ID; ?>); 

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: fd,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response){
            $('.upload-response').html(response); // Append Server Response
        }
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

In your plugin file, add:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','ajax_upload_script');
function ajax_upload_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-upload', plugins_url( '/js/upload.js' ), array('jquery'), '', true);
}

add_action('wp_ajax_my_upload_files', 'my_upload_files');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_upload_files', 'my_upload_files'); // Allow front-end submission 

function my_upload_files(){
//file handling here
}
```

Or if you don't want to make a plugin, add the actions to your child theme functions.php and change `plugins_url( '/js/upload.js' )` to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/upload.js'`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't want to upload a file. I want to pass a dataurl to php code and let it create the png file. So, it has to be an ajax call.

Comment: I'm passing canvas dataurl to it above. Change it to whatever dataurl info you need to pass

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a plugin like [PHP Code for posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-for-posts/). This would be better than hardcoding PHP into templates or WP Pages. The advantage is you can update and change the code easily and when updates are needed to WP, you do not need to re-apply your hardcoded PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you want implement ajax in wordpress than you need use wp_ajax hook.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)
add bellow code in function.php (theme folder)

javascript add in wp_footer hook on function.php

```
jQuery.post(
    ajaxurl, 
    {
        'action': 'add_foobar',
        'data':   'foobarid'
    }, 
    function(response){
        alert('The server responded: ' + response);
    }
);
```

below wp_ajax hook add on function.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );

function prefix_ajax_add_foobar() {
    // Handle request then generate response using WP_Ajax_Response

    // Don't forget to stop execution afterward.
    wp_die();
}
```

Those code will not update when you update Wordpress. but if possible than add those code on function.php on child theme so in case if you want update theme than not update those code.